# The [web.confg], [web.config] and [web-config] madness

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

So, today I noticed someone tagging their question with [web.confg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.confg). This is not correctly spelled, and apparently 123 other people couldn't spell either. web.config is at least a configuration file for IIS. The wiki says it is for an ASP.NET application.

I would propose of burning [web.confg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.confg) with an appropriate amount of fire. I would propose renaming [web-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-config) to [asp-web-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-web-config) or something along those lines and use [iis-web-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iis-web-config) for iis. I am not sure if either of those tags are really necessary though. Questions about iis are usually about it's config, so [iis-web-config] seems overkill to me.

Suggestions?

Comment: web.config isn't necessarily for ASP.NET websites - it's just sites running on IIS. so asp-web-config wouldn't be valid

Comment: why not web.config? web-config is more confusing. its not asp-net.

Comment: I disagree slightly with Joe's statement.
Websites running on IIS don't necessarily have a web.config - Classic ASP sites don't, nor would a PHP site.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config - "Web.config is the main settings and configuration file for an ASP.NET web application"

Which isn't to say someone couldn't create a web.config file for something that isn't ASP.NET - but predominantly it is used by ASP.NET.

That said I think the tag should be left as web.config - as I think it's self defining.

Comment: @ChrisNevill A PHP site on IIS can easily have a web.config, depending on where there the PHP handler mapping is defined.  Really anything hosted on ISS that has settings that differ from the server root will have a web.config.

Comment: That's true.  The lines are very blurred.  I wonder if it's a .NET component that reads the file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IIS uses and/or falls back to [machine.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and/or [applicationHost.config](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7), so `iis-web-config` wouldn't really be correct.

Renaming [web-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-config) to `asp-web-config` is also unnecessary and redundant; invariably the question will already be accompanied by an [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) tag.

As for the misspelling: it's quite clear it's a spelling mistake, so you shouldn't need to ask for burnination permission - just go through and correct it. The misspelled version will automatically be culled when it's no longer referenced.

Comment: It is a misspelling, but I don't know what to correct it to. I'll wait a bit if others think the tag should simply be omitted.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Just retag with the correct spelling (removing the incorrect one of course). There's no need to create any additional tags.

Comment: I see that someone edited all the web.confg questions, and since nothing else needs to be done I have marked this as the answer ;-)